# Select image tag attr from HTML without class or id

Tags: python, lxml

I have the HTML-page to parse via Python with Lxml. The problem is that I have to take from HTML image tags's values, which are without any class or id attributes. Like this:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody><tr>
<td align="left" valign="top" style="padding: 0 10px 0 60px;">
<img src="/files/135.jpg" width="64" height="64">
</td>
<td align="left" valign="middle"><h1>Archer / Арчер</h1>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

So, to solve my task I have the question  - is possible to write jquery-like expression to select image tags from this HTML or I have to extract attributes via iteration all img tags and getting the src-attribute, having the specific width and height ?

Comment: Could you please post more html code? Maybe we can use parent selectors.

Comment: I've updated my post, thanks. This is full HTML-code, containing img-tag. Upper is only body-tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [xpath](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) - supported by lxml.
You can use firepath addon for mozilla firefox to play with xpath a bit.
The end of your xpath expression can be like (width > 64 ?) 
............/img[@border="0"]

Answer (score 0):

This `xpath` query works on your sample data:

```
import lxml.html

root = lxml.html.fromstring('your sample data').getroottree()
root.xpath("//img[@width='64' and @height='64']/@src")
# ['/files/135.jpg']
```